# UIColor displays incorrect color

Tags: ios, uicolor

When I use UIColor and give R G B as input and then screen capture and check R G B values the values are not same! What is problem, is iOS applying a sort color management?

Comment: How are you performing the screen capture?  Are you doing this using the simulator or on a device?

Comment: Also, show an example of how you are specifying the UIColor.

Comment: Can you share your code in example format here?

Comment: can you share your code please.

Answer (score 0):

The screen-capture feature doesn't save with 100% accuracy. This happens because of performance-issues.

There is "mostly" nothing you can do about it, except editing the photo afterwards to get the exact color values you want.

*Edit 1*

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but under

```
Settings->Accessibility->Increase Contrast
```

you can choose to darken colors. Maybe this also affects your label, view or wherever you've set the UIColor.

Try turning it off

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing.  My experiment is showing an exact color match with both an iPhone 6 and an iPod touch 5.

Comment: I just tried that.  Neither the **Darken Colors** nor **Reduce White Point** settings under **Increase Contrast** affected the RGB colors of the screen captures.  They were still an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a little app that generates random colors for views and it displays the colors and RGB values in a table.  I ran this on an iPhone 6 and did a screen capture of the screens showing the colors and RGB values.  Then I used AirDrop to move the screen captures back to the Mac.  When I opened the screen captures in a photo editing program (Pixelmator), the RGB values *matched exactly* those values reported by the app.

I just repeated the experiment with an iPod touch 5th Generation (introduced Fall 2012), and again the colors matched exactly.

Here is an example screen capture:

[image: Example iPod screen capture]

---

**Update:**

Another poster suggested in the comments that perhaps the **Increase Contrast** settings under **Settings->Accessibility** were changing the RGB values.  I just tried changing both **Reduce White Point** and **Darken Colors** and found that while the screen looked different, the RGB values of the screen captures were still a match to the values reported by the app.